# Java with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

If u can suggest me about this error i will be helpful,i have tried several times but got stuck with this exception while trying to run spring mvc "hello world".thanx a lot in advance

```
Sep 08, 2015 8:45:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet mvc-dispatcher
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:395)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:340)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:307)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:817)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Sorry,My web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app version="2.5"   
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">  
 <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class> 
    <init-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param> 
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>  
<!--     <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>  
 -->
     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  

 </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

Controller is :-

```
package com.javatpoint;  
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;  

@Controller  
public class HelloWorldController {  
    @RequestMapping("/hello")  
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {  
        String message = "HELLO SPRING MVC HOW R U";  
        return new ModelAndView("index", "message",message);  
    } 
}
```

and spring-servlet-xml is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">  
    <context:component-scan  base-package="com.javatpoint" />  
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />  
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />  
    </bean>  
</beans>
```

Comment: Is the file there: /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml ?

Comment: what's the code to load it?

Comment: You should provide more information. Is the file actually there? What is your code  that fails?

Comment: yes file is already in the location.i have provided all the info.Could u plz check.thanx a lot in advance

Comment: @SOUVIKMAJI in your web.xml try changing <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value> to <param-value>classpath:spring-servlet.xml</param-value>

Comment: @smoggers bro i have changed the <param-value>classpath:spring-servlet.xml</param-value> as this,but now its showing, file does not exist in the classpath

Comment: can anyone plz try to check my code and let me know the results,I think it will be helpful.Waiting eagerly for reply

Answer (score -1):

Check whether you have configured the ServletContext in web.xml or not.
And check the configuration that you did in spring-servlet.xml also.
If you want to display the "hello world", firstly you have to write it in a JSP file, and after that, you have to add that file to ModelAndView object. And after that, you have to use the view resolvers like InternalResourceViewResolver for displaying that file(View of MVC)(which is containing "hello world"). You have to configure the view resolvers in the spring configuration file.

my jsp file is:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>mvc</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="hello.html">click</a>  
<br>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Place the jsp file outside the WEB-INF. Do undeploy of the project and then deploy again., and check..

Comment: Where did u configure your class "HelloWorldController"..?